# PHP array : How to separate array into new group array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, snmp

- i have array structure like this:

  Array(

  ```
    [1.1] => INTEGER: 1    
    [1.2] => INTEGER: 2    
    [1.3] => INTEGER: 3    
    [1.4] => INTEGER: 4    
    [1.5] => INTEGER: 5    
    [1.6] => INTEGER: 6    
    [2.1] => STRING: lo    
    [2.2] => STRING: eth0    
    [2.3] => STRING: eth1    
    [2.4] => STRING: wifi0    
    [2.5] => STRING: ath0    
    [2.6] => STRING: br0    
    [3.1] => INTEGER: softwareLoopback(24)    
    [3.2] => INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)    
    [3.3] => INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)    
    [3.4] => INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)    
    [3.5] => INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)    
    [3.6] => INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)
  ```

  )
- i need separate array into new group multidimensional arrays like this

  Array
  (
   [0] => array (
        [0] => INTEGER: 1
        [1] => STRING: lo
        [2] => INTEGER: softwareLoopback(24)
    )
  .....
   )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always groups of 6, then chunk and transpose:

```
$myArray = [
  '1.1' => 'INTEGER: 1',    
  '1.2' => 'INTEGER: 2',    
  '1.3' => 'INTEGER: 3',    
  '1.4' => 'INTEGER: 4',    
  '1.5' => 'INTEGER: 5',    
  '1.6' => 'INTEGER: 6',    
  '2.1' => 'STRING: lo',    
  '2.2' => 'STRING: eth0',    
  '2.3' => 'STRING: eth1',    
  '2.4' => 'STRING: wifi0',    
  '2.5' => 'STRING: ath0',    
  '2.6' => 'STRING: br0',
  '3.1' => 'INTEGER: softwareLoopback(24)',
  '3.2' => 'INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)',  
  '3.3' => 'INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)',  
  '3.4' => 'INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)',  
  '3.5' => 'INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)',    
  '3.6' => 'INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)',
];

$newArray = call_user_func_array(
    'array_map',
    array_merge(
        array(NULL),
        array_chunk($myArray, 6)
    )
);
var_dump($newArray);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/evNCax)

Answer (score 0):

Reindex your input array in "standard way" (I mean indexes 0, 1, 2...) and then you can write following function

```
$a = array(1,2,3,21,22,23,31,32,33); // input array - example

function rearrange($a) {
    $r = array();
    $count = count($a) / 3;

    for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $r[$i] = array(
                0 => $a[$i],
                1 => $a[$i+$count],
                2 => $a[$i+2*$count]
            );
        }
    return ($r);
}  

var_dump($a);
$a = rearrange($a);
var_dump($a);
```